# How do install and start daemon Docker in an Alpine container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I work from Docker on Windows 11. I use Dockerfile to create an image:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk add docker
RUN apk add openrc
```

When viewing the Docker version in the Alpine image, I get:

```
Docker version 23.0.6, build ef23cbc4315ae76c744e02d687c09548ede461bd
```

When I want to look at the docker status, I enter:

```
status service docker
```

But I get an error:

```
 * You are attempting to run an openrc service on a
 * system which openrc did not boot.
 * You may be inside a chroot or you may have used
 * another initialization system to boot this system.
 * In this situation, you will get unpredictable results!
 * If you really want to do this, issue the following command:
 * touch /run/openrc/softlevel
```

Next I enter what is prepositional (touch /run/openrc/softlevel)
and get another error:

```
touch: /run/openrc/softlevel: No such file or directory
```

After that I want to check the list of images:

```
docker images
```

return:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

And final commands:

```
service docker start
```

return:

```
* WARNING: docker is already starting
```

And:

```
service docker stop
```

return:

```
* ERROR: docker stopped by something else
```

I don't understand what's the matter at all, since I'm a beginner to using Linux.

Comment: Alpine is good for many things, but I'd wager running Docker-in-Docker is not one of them. Pull the [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) from Docker Hub instead.

Comment: That all said, you can run Docker on Windows, which will negate the need for Docker-in-Docker. Could you do that instead?

Comment: @halfer I found an option to access docker alpine from docker windows and it looks reliable so far:
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

Comment: @HansKilian: I am interested in learning more about your statement. I have always assumed D-in-D implies nested containers, and [this resource](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/) would suggest that my assumption was correct. Could you point me to an authoritative resource that might suggest otherwise?

Comment: @Goro: right, so your host is Windows, you have Docker images running on it, and you want to access the Docker containers from inside an Alpine container. Sharing the socket is a way to do that, correct. Your check of the Docker service in Alpine would be checking a (separate) Docker host in Alpine, rather than the one that is already running on the Windows host.

Comment: @halfer Reading up on it, it seems that you're right. It does mean running the daemon inside a container. I've deleted my comment.

Comment: @HansKilian: thanks! I've used D-in-D before (at least in my understanding of it) in hosted CI systems like CircleCI. There are some gotchas to be aware of that do not apply to a single level of container abstraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify the discussion in the comments, and the solution you found, it sounds like you have a Windows host onto which Docker Desktop is installed. You have an Alpine container in which the Docker client command is installed. You issued a basic command (`docker images`) inside the running container and found that it did not work. This is because, by the default, the console command will expect Docker is running locally (in this case in the container).

Your solution was thus:

```
docker run \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    ...
```

This has the effect of sharing the Unix socket from the host (where Docker is running) to the container (where you only have a client, not a server).

This technique is helpful if you want to run some code in isolation from the host, but you still need access to your existing Docker images.

Comment: Yes, I did it, and I was able to work with windows docker from a container, but it didn't help me in any way

Comment: @Goro: can you explain how it did not help you? What are you actually wanting to achieve?

Comment: Ah, I wonder if I spot a problem. Is your Windows Docker set up for Windows containers? If so I am not sure there will be much compatibility if you try to interact with them in a Alpine Linux environment.

Comment: Everything is standard on my windows docker, I haven't changed anything. My main task was to run GitLab + GitLab-Runner locally in separate containers to run integration tests (postgres testcontainer)
in the GitLab pipeline. One problem was solved (what was discussed here), but the following problem appeared after it. Now docker image testcontainer just can't start.
As a result, I registered on the Gitlab website and run Gitlab-runner from windows and so everything works.

Comment: @Goro: it's best if we don't assume what "standard" means on Windows. There are a lot of ways to accomplish Docker running on Windows. Are you using Docker Desktop? If so, are you in [Windows or Linux container mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-10-linux)?

Comment: I appreciate you have a remote Docker workaround, but I would urge you to get this working locally - it will probably take ten minutes once you have supplied sufficient information about your system.

Comment: I use docker desktop, and linux containers

Comment: @Goro: OK. It sounds like my write-up is your first solution, and you have bumped into a new problem. This is normal when you are getting used to Docker, you'll get the hang of it. Would you create a new question for the actual problem? This would summarise what you do have working (Alpine Linux container running on Windows, pointing to the Docker Desktop instance of Docker) and what does not work (i.e. what errors you get when trying to start testcontainer, what command you are using, and where you are running that, etc).

Comment: Yes, thanks for the help, it just takes a lot of time, so I'll take a break for now and when the opportunity arises, I'll figure out what the problem was.